# MYSQL hopelessly corrupted?

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am using xampp stack to create a website but recently had to upgrade my OS and xampp stopped working.

MySql server would not launch in the new OS. I looked around here for solutions and found a lot that said I should delete the `Ibdata` file.

I did and it solved my initial problem but now MYSQL is close to useless. Every database is giving an error and trying to create a new one just keeps on loading forever.

Is there any way to fix this? to reset MYSQL to initial state or something? I dont need to recover the databases as they were only tests I just need to be able to create new ones but nothing works anymore.

Comment: NOTE: phpMyAdmin is a tool wriiten in PHP to simplify the maintenance of a **MYSQL** database.

Comment: @apaandmomo you should be more specific - which errors have you received? how did you produce them? please quote the errors and describe the steps required to re-produce them

Comment: If you are using INNODB databases (and that is the default now) They store their data in the `ibdata` file (all databases in the one file). If you deleted that, then you deleted you databases basically.

Comment: You are going to have to restore your databases from your last backup

Comment: getting errors similar to Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist in engine